# Dynamic Yii input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I add this `Yii` input to my form:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'contact_type_id',$model->getContactParams(), array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

Is it possible to add this input dynamically with jQuery?

Comment: you want to add a select box, dynamically in jquery??

Comment: yes. I want to add dropdown dynamically

Comment: is the dropdown values static?? or you need to fetch from database??

Comment: Dropdown values are dynamic, fetched from the DB

Comment: you need to use ajax for this. on which action you want to add the dropdowns??

Comment: On click. I have this code to add strings: $('#addContact').click(function() {
     $('#row').append(
      '<div class="contact"><br><div class="col-md-6">contact type</div><div class="col-md-6"></div></div>'
      );
     return false;
 });

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for this.

```
 $('#addContact').click(function() {

      $.ajax({
            url: "your url here",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            async: false,
            data: {"name":value},//if you want to send any data.
            success: function(data) {
                        //     here append the select to required div.                     
            }
      });
 });
```

In the url, you fetch the data from database and print there.

Comment: with your existing append, call ajax and add the select to your page.

Comment: can you provide an example? I'm new to jquery

Comment: what type of example you want?? live demo?/

Comment: but i think you carry with the answer, i ll help u in case of any problems